# How to make consistent sampling from several Mixture distributions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to be able to get consistent samples from several Mixture distributions. I.e., for example, my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Mixture, Normal, Deterministic, Categorical
import numpy as np

rate = 0.5 

cat = Categorical(probs=[1-rate, rate])

f1 = Mixture(cat=cat, components=[Normal(loc=10., scale=1.), Deterministic(0.)])
f2 = Mixture(cat=cat, components=[Normal(loc=5., scale=1.), Deterministic(0.)])

sess = tf.Session()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)

sess.run([cat.sample(), f1.sample(), f2.sample()])
```

I get:

```
[1, 10.4463625, 0.0]
```

Which is not what I desire, cause they are drawn independently, which makes sense if one takes a look at the source code of `.sample()` method.

My question: how can I draw samples so that `Categorical` variable would be evaluated first and it would be shared between `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: how about using `cat_sample = cat.sample()` and then `Mixture(cat=cat_sample, ...)`?

Comment: @mikkola I thought about it, unfortunatelly, it gives `TypeError: cat must be a Categorical distribution, but saw: Tensor("Categorical_1/sample/Reshape_2:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
`

Answer (score 0):

There is no very clean way of achieving this with existing library code (though there is an internal bug along these lines).

For now, you can create a dummy categorical distribution that returns the same a cached sampled tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import Mixture, Normal, Deterministic, Categorical
import numpy as np

class HackedCat(tf.distributions.Categorical):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(HackedCat, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self._cached_sample = self.sample(use_cached=False)

  def sample(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Use cached sample by default or when explicitly asked to
    if 'use_cached' not in kwargs or kwargs['use_cached']:
      return self._cached_sample
    else:
      if 'use_cached' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['use_cached']
      return super(HackedCat, self).sample(*args, **kwargs)

def main():
  rate = 0.5 
  cat = HackedCat(probs=[1-rate, rate])
  f1 = Mixture(cat=cat,
               components=[Normal(loc=10., scale=1.),
                           Deterministic(0.)])
  f2 = Mixture(cat=cat,
               components=[Normal(loc=5., scale=1.),
                           Deterministic(0.)])

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
    print sess.run([cat.sample(), f1.sample(), f2.sample()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```